# Vue Store Methods inside Array/Object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

let's say we have 5 buttons with exactly same features. This is why I thought rather than copying and pasting these 5 buttons why I wouldn't use v-for.

```
methods: {
    a() {}, 
    b() {},
    ...
}
```

Rather than

```
<v-btn block color="primary" class="my-1" @click="a">A</v-btn>
<v-btn block color="primary" class="my-1" @click="b">B</v-btn>
<v-btn block color="primary" class="my-1" @click="c">C</v-btn>
<v-btn block color="primary" class="my-1" @click="d">D</v-btn>
<v-btn block color="primary" class="my-1" @click="e">E</v-btn>
```

Tried to use

```
 <v-btn v-for="(button, index) in buttons" :key="index"
      block color="primary" class="my-1" 
      @click="button.click">{{button.text}}
 </v-btn>

buttons: [
        { click: this.a, text: "A"},
        { click: this.b, text: "B"},
        { click: this.c, text: "C"},
        { click: this.d, text: "D"},
        { click: this.e, text: "E"},
      ]
```

- It works as expected, however when I try to render this buttons object I am getting something like this. Why clicks are not there ?

  ```
  [ { "text": "A" }, { "text": "B" }, { "text": "C" }, { "text": "D" }, { "text": "E" } ]
  ```
- Let's go one more step, and let's add a button with dynamic text (another data field)

  ```
  boolean: true
  F: "data1"

  f() {boolean ? this.F = "data1" : "data2"}
  <v-btn block color="primary" class="my-1" @click="F">{{F}}</v-btn>
  ```

This time I am getting

```
[ { "text": "A" }, { "text": "B" }, { "text": "C" }, { "text": "D" }, { "text": "E" }, {} ]
```

The button text doesn't change, however when I render {{F}} I am seeing the data changes.

- What is the reason behind this, and how to handle this kind of situations ?

I have tried to create a method such as setButtons and returning buttons array and set buttons field, this time when I render buttons I am getting whole object as expected but when the data changes such as F, object isn't updated again.

Comment: have many errors, but when you make `@click="a"` this specs a `function` called `a()` inside of `methods` property.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct you want to render a method into a `@click` from a for-loop?

you can create a helper function to deal with it.

here `bindFunction()` will take the string `button.click` and return a `function`

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
        buttons: [
        { click: "toggleA", text: "A" },
        { click: "toggleB", text: "B" },
        { click: "toggleC", text: "C" },
        { click: "toggleD", text: "D" },
        { click: "toggleE", text: "E" }
      ]
  },
  methods: {
   bindFunction(f) {
      this[f]();
    },
    toggleA() {
      console.log("toggleA");
    },
    toggleB() {
      console.log("toggleB");
    },
    toggleC() {
      console.log("toggleC");
    },
    toggleD() {
      console.log("toggleD");
    },
    toggleE() {
      console.log("toggleE");
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
    <div v-for="(button, index) of buttons" :key="index">
      <button @click="bindFunction(button.click)">{{button.text}}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, this might work but this is (  { click: this.a, text: "A"} ) already working no problem with that. I was just asking why I can't see clicks when I render {{buttons}} in template. Also why can't I set another vue prop inside this buttons array.